# How to change the style of an element which is not there in the source code (of a php file)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been working on a certain webpage which is a php file. A combo box is one of the outputs that can be seen on this page. In order to make that combo box responsive I need to set its width to 100%. A span element can be seen when inspecting the page via developer tools and when adjusting the width of that span element, the width of the combo box gets adjusted. But that span element is not there in the source code. How can I change the width of this combo box?

The part where the combo box is created is as follows: Please note that I am just getting started and don't have much knowledge about how this works. What I do know is that there are several scripts imported and they might be the ones that are responsible for completing the rest of the combo box.

```
<div class="col" style="width: 100%">
    <select name="chooseHub" class="text-input" id="chooseHub" required="required" >
        <option style="width: 100%"></option>
        <?php
        $hubList = $jsonHubList;

        foreach ($hubList as $key => $value) {
            if ($value->isActive) {
                ?>
                <option style="width: 100%" value="<?php echo $value->idHub."_".$value->city?>"  ><?php echo $value->name ?></option>

                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the element shown on the developer tools whose width when changed changes the width of the combo box:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 477px;">
```

If you need further information please mention it on the comment section.

I tried changing the width of the div elements surrounding the select including that of the select element and option elements but none of which seemed to work out.

I changed the width of the span element from the developer tools (shown in the 2nd code snippet I have put) and that worked out. Afterwards I put a script at the end of the source code trying to catch that span element either by its tag name or the class name but apparently since no such element exists in the source code it did not work.

Comment: It looks like the page is using Select2 library, please consult [the documentation](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width) to find out how you can control the width of the drop-box.

Comment: @Teemu You were right the page is using Select2 library, and I followed the documentation(Thank you for sending it to me) but still it did not work. Setting a value according to the documentation did set the width of the drop box but still it is not responsive.

Comment: Notice, that passing a fixed width value to `.select2` overrides the inline style of the original select element, setting inline width [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/o3amwjgh/).